# Save selected values of input despite switching between two components in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js

So I have two components that are imported into my app.vue:

```
<script>
import Leaderboard from "./components/Comp1.vue";
import Search from "./components/Comp2.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Comp1,
    Comp2,
  },
}
```

These components are called, when I click on the corresponding button. This all works fine.

But in the components I have some input fields such as in Comp1.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
<select
   class="form-select"
   name="event"
   id=""
   v-model="selectedEvent"
   >
            <option value="">Please choose an event:</option>
            <option v-for="event in eventsList" :key="event">
              {{ event }}
            </option>
  </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
data: function () {
        return {
            selectedEvent: "",
</script>
```

Here I can choose, which event to watch. But after switching to Comp2 and then again choosing Comp1, the `selectedEvent` is empty. Obviously, because its defined empty in `data`.

Is there any way to store the selected value in a session variable or would you prefer a different technique?

UI looks like this:[image: UI]

Comment: can you add  a screenshot of your UI as well?

Comment: @Amaarrockz done! Hope, thats what you wanted

Comment: You can make use of `local storage` to store the value you selected or you can also go for using the `vuex` library for maintaining the state.

Comment: You could also use a `keep-alive` on your components to remember their last state, more info here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

Comment: Or have more data like selectedEventComp1 and selectedEventComp2, and store the value there. Lot of possible solutions. :)

Comment: yes Iam adding my answer

Comment: Thanks @YashMaheshwari I tried that and it worked, but I will also check out using ```keep-alive```. Thanks guys!

Comment: @TobiasSchnier - if your create a form like thing with multiple pages then its better to have it as a mainObject in the parent without loading your client [localStorage]

Comment: I have added a solution for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain an Object in your parent which you can pass as props to a props and then have a two way handshake

```
<Leaderboard :formInputs="formInputs"></Leaderboard>
```

```
<script>
import Leaderboard from "./components/Comp1.vue";
import Search from "./components/Comp2.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Comp1,
    Comp2,
  },
  data() {
   return {
    formInputs: {
      compOneInput: '',
      compTwpInput: ''
    }
},
methods: {
  updateData(payload) {
   this.formInputs[payload.key] = payload.value;
 }
}
```

and then pass this formInputs to your child Component from where you
you can emit the change whenever you update the input inside that

```
<template>
  <div>
<select
   class="form-select"
   name="event"
   id=""
   v-model="selectedEvent"
   >
            <option value="">Please choose an event:</option>
            <option v-for="event in eventsList" :key="event">
              {{ event }}
            </option>
  </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data: function () {
        return {
            selectedEvent: this.formInputs.compOneInput ? this.formInputs.compOneInput : '',
      }
 },
 watch: {
   formInputs(newVal) {
    this.selectedEvent = newVal.compOneInput;
   },
   selectedEvent(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal !== oldVal) {
      this.$emit('updateData', {key: compOneInput, value: this.selectedEvent});
    }
  }
 }
 props: {
   formInputs: Object
 }
}

</script>
```

Using the above example for component one , you can implement the same for component two also

Answer (score 0):

you can add a watcher on selectedEvent then store the data in vuex store